# memcached default port should be changed?

Tags: nginx

I'm using memcached on a ubuntu 14.04 based server with nginx on it

It's default setting is:

```
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:11211"
```

Should it be changed to some other port? Or is it secure like this too?

Appreciate your thoughts, thanks.

Comment: IMO changing ports adds little if any security. Anyone interested in cracking you will simply do a port scan ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMO changing ports adds little if any security. Anyone interested in cracking you will simply do a port scan ;)

By default you can only connect from localhost anyways so , IMO you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default port is often a good idea but conceals a false sense of security. An interested cracker would start a port scan and would not be satisfied with the scan of the default ports.

The restriction of access to defined areas of the network offer additional protection. In your case, for example, the restriction on your local area network or only on your machine, the localhost.

Thus, your configuration will be considered sufficiently secure.

If you're interested in more security: TCP-Wrapper and iptables

Comment: how to restrict access to defined areas?

Comment: i mean. do we need to do this with memcached? or not needed?

Comment: As I said, your configuration is ok.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`

Comment: where did you mean that? 0_o

Comment: In a (deleted) comment before I have mentioned the wrong file names.